# Remove data from cdc table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, change-data-capture

I am using CDC in sql 2008 and i want that whenever cleanup job executed it only removes data from cdc table which is one month older then current date . Is this possible ?

Comment: You can refer here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645885(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
exec sp_cdc_change_job @job_type='cleanup', @retention=43200 -- minutes
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?